# crontab arguments

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi

I understand that `crontab -e` is used to edit the current crontab.
If i create a file named abc and put a cron command in it and type `crontab abc`, I believe this is to set the current cron file to the contents of the file abc.  I assumed that now, the current crontab setting is the contents of the file abc.

But now, when I type `crontab -e`, the listing that shows does not have my cron command in it.

Is my understanding wrong? I thought I could use `crontab -e` or `crontab filename` to do the same thing.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, and you therefore need to show the exact commands that you are using and what happens when you run them. Copy and paste from your terminal into a code block in your question.

Comment: `crontab -e` itself does not output a listing. It just runs up an editor to let you alter the crontab file interactively, and the editor is the command defined by `export EDITOR=vim` or whatever you choose: there is a default but it varies per-distro. `crontab -l` lists the file. Also, `crontab` on most distros refuses to write an invalid file, so that may be your problem.

Comment: Are you editing abc *after* running crontab on it and expecting those changes to get picked up by crond?

Answer (score 0):

> If i create a file named abc and put a cron command in it and type `crontab abc`, I believe this is to set the current cron file to the contents of the file abc.

If you meant "the crontab file **of the user that ran the `crontab abc` command**", then yes.

Are you running `crontab -e` using the same user account you used to run `crontab abc` with? Each user has their own crontab file, and the system administrator usually also has a system-wide `/etc/crontab` file that can (and must) specify the username the commands should run as.

If you ran `crontab abc` as root and are now trying to run `crontab -e` as a regular user, then the `crontab abc` would have set `root`'s crontab, which the regular user certainly cannot edit.